# i want 3 records on one page when pressing ctrl +p to print that page of a php application

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php session_start();
require_once('SessionSet.php');
require_once('connection.php');
include('top.php');
if(isset($_GET['ClassID']) && isset($_GET['SectionId']) )
{
 $ClassID = $_GET['ClassID'];
 
 $SectionId = $_GET['SectionId'];
 
 $ClassName = $_GET['ClassName'];
 
 $SectionName = $_GET['SectionName'];
 
 $GetCurrentMonth = date('M');
 
 /* select latest Academic Year*/
 
 $GetAcademicQ = "select * from study_year order by StudyYearId desc limit 1";
 
 $GetAcademicQR = mysqli_query($con,$GetAcademicQ);
 
 $GetAcademicRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetAcademicQR);
 
 $AcademciyearId =  $GetAcademicRow['StudyYearId'];
 
 $YearName =  $GetAcademicRow['YearName'];
 
 /* Get Students and Students Class + Fee Records */
 
 $GetStudentClassQ = "select * from studentclass where 
    AcademicYearId='$AcademciyearId' and StudentClassId='$ClassID'
    and StudentSectionId='$SectionId';";
 
 $GetStudentClassQR = mysqli_query($con,$GetStudentClassQ);
 
 $GetStudentClassNum = mysqli_num_rows($GetStudentClassQR);
 
 if($GetStudentClassNum>0)
 {
  while($GetStudentClassRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetStudentClassQR))
  {
   $StudentID = $GetStudentClassRow['StudentID'];
   $RollNumber = $GetStudentClassRow['RollNumber'];
   $RollNumber = $GetStudentClassRow['RollNumber'];
   $StuentClassFee = $GetStudentClassRow['StuentClassFee'];
   
   
   /* Get Stduent Name and bio data */
   
   $GetStudentQ = "select * from students where Student_ID='$StudentID';";
   
   $GetStudentQR = mysqli_query($con,$GetStudentQ);
   
   $GetStudentRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetStudentQR);
   
   $Name  = $GetStudentRow['Name'];
   $FatherName  = $GetStudentRow['FatherName'];
   $StudentPhoto  = $GetStudentRow['StudentPhoto'];
   $Student_ID  = $GetStudentRow['Student_ID'];
            
            /* Get Stduent Name and bio data */
   
   $GetfeeQ = "select * from fee where FeeStudentID='$StudentID';";
   
   $GetfeeQR = mysqli_query($con,$GetfeeQ);
   
   $GetfeeRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetfeeQR);
   
   $FeeAmount  = $GetfeeRow['FeeAmount'];
   $FeePaid  = $GetfeeRow['FeePaid'];
   
   ?>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered print-table" style="width:100% !important" align="center">

<!--Office Copy-->
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $Student_ID;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ClassName;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Section Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $SectionName;?>
                        </td>

                        <th>Roll Number</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $RollNumber;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Academic Year </th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $YearName;?>
                        </td>
                        
                        <!--td rowspan="5" style="text-align:center"><img src="StudentImages/<?php/* echo $StudentPhoto;*/?>"/ alt="Stdudent Image not found" style="width:150px; height:200px"></td-->
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <?php echo $Name;?>
                        </td>

                        <th>Father Name</th>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <?php echo $FatherName;?>
                        </td>
                                    
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Fee Month </th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $GetCurrentMonth;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Fee Amount</th>
                        <td style="font-size:20px;">
                            <?php echo $StuentClassFee;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Previous Dues</th>
                        <td style="font-size:20px;">
                            <?php echo $FeeAmount-$FeePaid;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <td>12 -
                            <?php echo $GetCurrentMonth;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>After Due Date</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $StuentClassFee+50;?>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                      
                    <hr>
<!--Student Copy-->
                    

                </table>
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered print-table" style="width:100% !important" align="center" >
                                      <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $Student_ID;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $ClassName;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Section Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $SectionName;?>
                        </td>

                        <th>Roll Number</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $RollNumber;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Academic Year </th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $YearName;?>
                        </td>
                        
                        <!--td rowspan="5" style="text-align:center"><img src="StudentImages/<?php/* echo $StudentPhoto;*/?>"/ alt="Stdudent Image not found" style="width:150px; height:200px"></td-->
                    </tr>
                    
                <tr class="warning">
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $Name;?>
                        </td>

                        <th>Father Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $FatherName;?>
                        </td>
    
                        <th>Fee Month </th>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $GetCurrentMonth;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Fee Amount</th>
                        <td style="font-size:20px;">
                            <?php echo $StuentClassFee;?>
                        </td>
                        <th>Previous Dues</th>
                        <td style="font-size:20px;">
                            <?php echo $FeeAmount-$FeePaid;?>
                        </td>
                                              
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- row end here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- page-wrapper end here -->
    <?php
   
   
  }
 }
 else
 {
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
?>








        <?php
}
?>
```

i am building a php school management application. when I try to print report after pressing ctrl+p one recored is being shown on each page. but i want to show atleast 3 records on a single page after giving printing command. I have attached snapshots of records before and after print command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvp3D.png)

here is picture after giving print command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYhgC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with PHP, this is a question about CSS, specifically print styles.

In the absence of an example of plain HTML and CSS, take a look at the CSS properties `page-break-before`, `page-break-after` and `page-break-inside`. In this case you may want to look at something like:

```
@media print {
  .row, table {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```

Learn a little bit more about the `page-break-*` properties at [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/). If you are generally new to CSS print styles, [I wrote a primer for .NET magazine](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/make-your-website-printable-css-3132929).

Bear in mind that whatever styles you use, these are only suggestions to the browser. Paper size, page orientation, font size, zoom level, user margins, etc. will all work together to mess with your plans. Content that you force to be too wide for the page may also be an issue.

Finally, don't use any inline styles. Use your CSS file for that (so get rid of that `width:100%` inline style I saw.

If you want more help, post the raw HTML output and your CSS.

Comment: but my page is already being broken and I don't want it to break

Comment: That is why I used the `avoid` keyword.